# Generation of XML from List of arrays of String in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, csv

I am using `opencsv` to parse text file and generate `List<String[]>` now I want to generate `XML` from `List<String[]>` and so my question is do we have any `3rd Party Libraries` that does that conversion, if not, what would be an better approach to solve the issue.

Here is the `Parsing Logic:`

```
    public class ParseFile {

    public ParseFile() {

    }

    public void getQuotes() {
        String fileName = "C:\\GS.txt";
        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), '\t');
            String[] nextLine;
            List<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            dataList = reader.readAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ParseFile test = new ParseFile();
        test.getQuotes();
        System.out.println("Parsing Done Successfully....");
    }
}
```

So my `txt` file looks like:

```
Header Information: ContractDate Trader  Quantity
1st Line of Data:   03/23/12     GS      100
```

and I need to have `XML Structure` like:

```
<root>
  <entry id='1'>
    <ContractDate>03/23/12</ContractDate>
    <Trader>GS</Trader>
    <Quantity>100</Quantity>
  </entry>
</root>
```

Comment: I don't know of any third party libraries that would be any easier than just writing something custom.  Since the data seems to be tab or white space delimited, I would probably just use StringTokenizer to break the text file up and reserialize as XML in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't explicitly require a 3rd party library to generate your rather simple XML format. You could simply write a to a StringBuffer object:

```
...
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("<root>");
for (String[] row: dataList) {
  sb.append("<entry>");
  sb.append("<ContractDate>").append(row[0]).append("</ContractDate>");
  // etc...
  sb.append("</entry>");
}
sb.append("</root>");
...
```

However, I'm not necessarily advocating it. I personally recommend [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php). Create a POJO to model your rows (I won't include all properties in my example):

```
@Root
public class Entry {

  @Element
  private String trader;

  @Attribute
  private int id;

  public Entry() {
    super();
  }  

  public String getTrader() {
    return text;
  }

  public void setTrader(String trader) {
    this.trader = trader;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

@Root(name="root")
public class Entries {
   @ElementList(inline=true)
   List<Entry> entries;

   public Entries(List<Entry> entries) {
     this.entries = entries;
   }
}
```

It's certainly some extra work up-front, but for non-trivial programs, having proper Java classes to represent the data models makes a lot of sense and provides greater flexibility, and code clarity.

To save save as XML you do this:

```
 List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList();
 int entryCount = 0;
 Serializer serializer = new Persister();
 for (String[] row: dataList) {
   Entry entry = new Entry();
   entry.setTrader(row[1]);
   entry.setId(++entryCount);
   entryList.add(entry);
 }
 File result = new File("entries.xml");
 serializer.write(new Entries(entryList), result);
```

The Simple XML library gives you a lot of flexibility. You can also load up the XML file back into a list of Entry objects.

Comment: I do not understand part where we need to map stuff into pojo from txt file, i have already parsed my txt and got data as `List<String[]>`?

Comment: Mapping may be overkill in your fairly simple case, but I thought I included it because IMHO it's better to be working with classes which model your data rather than Lists of Arrays of Strings. So although you don't *need* to do it that way, I think it can make your code clearer and more flexible should the codebase expand to include more sophisticated features.

Answer (score 1):

I would use JAXB - http://jaxb.java.net/ - you can build a POJO, annotate it with JAXB and then write it to an XML.

Comment: And if you already have the XML schema, you can even work the other way around and generate the Java classes from the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is simple enough.  I would just iterate over your data in a loop and write out the XML using a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n");
builder.append("<root>\n");

int entryId = 1;
for (String[] data : dataList) {
  builder.append("\t<entry id='" + entryId++ + "'>\n");
  builder.append("\t\t<ContractDate>" + data[0] + "</ContractDate>\n");
  // etc
}

builder.append("</root>\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) would good solution for you. It is a great and simple API for read/Write XML and more ... :)

Your example with XStream:

```
public class ParseFile {

public ParseFile() {

}

public void getQuotes() {
    String fileName = "C:\\GS.txt";
    try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), '\t');
        String[] nextLine;
        List<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        dataList = reader.readAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

//Convert to XML with XStream
XStream xstream = new XStream();
String xmlContent = xstream.toXML( dataList );

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ParseFile test = new ParseFile();
    test.getQuotes();
    System.out.println("Parsing Done Successfully....");
}
}
```

Comment: Where will this generated XML written into?

Comment: `XStream` is good library but it does not gives `xml tags` that i need but it gives tags like `list`, `string-array`, `string`, but i need to have tags like `ContractDate`, `Trader` and `Quantity`